# (excel Data Validation:) How to apply multi conditional and interdependent data validation

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns (Increment Rating & Promotion) where a user has to provide her input.
The "increment rating" input is restricted from Min (0.5) to Max (4.5) and the "Promotion" input is restricted to "Yes" or "No".

I know that for, Increment Rating I can apply the decimal validation criterion between Min & Max values, and for Promotion, I can apply the "list" criterion.

However, IF the user has entered the max value (i.e. 4.5) in the first column (i.e. Increment Rating), then Promotion must not be "Yes". It has to be either No or Blank (And I also need to show an error message saying that "This is not allowed"). On the other hand, IF the user is filling the second column (i.e. Promotion) before the first column and selects "Yes" as input then Increment Rating can not be more than Max-1 (i.e. 4.5-1=3.5) and need to show an error message here as well.

Is it possible with data validation custom formula? Or someone can help with #VBA.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a table featuring the allowed data values for each input row and then refer to that table with relative references (i.e. no row fixing with $).

Here below is an example of such a table with formulas that adjust the allowed data values conditional on the input already provided. Note that the rows in the 'Source' section of the data validation window are not fixed.

[image]

Such that, when selecting the drop down window of those cells that have a list, you can see how the list is conditional on the table on the right.

[image]

If the input is done one cell after another (and not through copy and paste over both columns and once) an error message should not be needed since both columns have data validation restrictions conditional on one another.

You do not have to re-do the data validation for every row but simply select all input rows of one column and use relative reference instead of absolute reference in the 'Source' field of the data validation window.